# SolidJS: input field loses focus when typing

Tags: arrays, input, focus, solid-js

I have a newbie question on SolidJS. I have an array with objects, like a to-do list. I render this as a list with input fields to edit one of the properties in these objects. When typing in one of the input fields, the input directly loses focus though.

How can I prevent the inputs to lose focus when typing?

Here is a CodeSandbox example demonstrating the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/6s8y2x?file=/src/main.tsx

Here is the source code demonstrating the issue:

```js
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import { createSignal, For } from 'solid-js'

function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = createSignal([
    { id: 1, text: 'cleanup' },
    { id: 2, text: 'groceries' },
  ])

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>Todos</h2>
        <p>
          Problem: whilst typing in one of the input fields, they lose focus
        </p>
        <For each={todos()}>
          {(todo, index) => {
            console.log('render', index(), todo)
            return <div>
              <input
                value={todo.text}
                onInput={event => {
                  setTodos(todos => {
                    return replace(todos, index(), {
                      ...todo,
                      text: event.target.value
                    })
                  })
                }}
              />
            </div>
          }}
        </For>
        Data: {JSON.stringify(todos())}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

/*
 * Returns a cloned array where the item at the provided index is replaced
 */
function replace<T>(array: Array<T>, index: number, newItem: T) : Array<T> {
  const clone = array.slice(0)
  clone[index] = newItem
  return clone
}

render(() => <App />, document.getElementById("app")!);
```

UPDATE: I've worked out a CodeSandbox example with the problem and the three proposed solutions (based on two answers): https://codesandbox.io/s/solidjs-input-field-loses-focus-when-typing-itttzy?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`<For>` components keys items of the input array by the reference.
When you are updating a todo item inside todos with `replace`, you are creating a brand new object. Solid then treats the new object as a completely unrelated item, and creates a fresh HTML element for it.

You can use `createStore` instead, and update only the single property of your todo object, without changing the reference to it.

```js
const [todos, setTodos] = createStore([
   { id: 1, text: 'cleanup' },
   { id: 2, text: 'groceries' },
])
const updateTodo = (id, text) => {
   setTodos(o => o.id === id, "text", text)
}
```

Or use an alternative Control Flow component for mapping the input array, that takes an explicit key property:
https://github.com/solidjs-community/solid-primitives/tree/main/packages/keyed#Key

```
<Key each={todos()} by="id">
   ...
</Key>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this explains it very clearly. I wasn't aware of the `solid-primitives` library, that looks like a neat solution. I now understand that `createStore` apparently works different than `createSignal` in this regard, the todo's example that I was looking at on the website also uses a `createStore`.

Comment: awesome! saved me lot of time to dig in deeper. Well explained.

Answer (score 3):

While @thetarnav solutions work, I want to propose my own.
I would solve it by using `<Index>`

```
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import { createSignal, Index } from "solid-js";

/*
 * Returns a cloned array where the item at the provided index is replaced
 */
function replace<T>(array: Array<T>, index: number, newItem: T): Array<T> {
  const clone = array.slice(0);
  clone[index] = newItem;
  return clone;
}

function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = createSignal([
    { id: 1, text: "cleanup" },
    { id: 2, text: "groceries" }
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>Todos</h2>
        <p>
          Problem: whilst typing in one of the input fields, they lose focus
        </p>
        <Index each={todos()}>
          {(todo, index) => {
            console.log("render", index, todo());
            return (
              <div>
                <input
                  value={todo().text}
                  onInput={(event) => {
                    setTodos((todos) => {
                      return replace(todos, index, {
                        ...todo(),
                        text: event.target.value
                      });
                    });
                  }}
                />
              </div>
            );
          }}
        </Index>
        Dat: {JSON.stringify(todos())}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
render(() => <App />, document.getElementById("app")!);
```

As you can see, instead of the `index` being a function/signal, now the object is. This allows the framework to replace the value of the textbox inline.
To remember how it works: For remembers your objects by reference. If your objects switch places then the same object can be reused. `Index` remembers your values by index. If the value at a certain index is changed then that is reflected in the signal.

This solution is not more or less correct than the other one proposed, but I feel this is more in line and closer to the core of Solid.

Comment: Yup, it fixes the problem just as well, and even without extra dependencies or refactoring the state logic. One thing worth mentioning though: Adding/Removing items in the middle of the array; or swapping them around will cause similar problems with rendering as with the original issue. So go ahead, but use with caution.

Comment: Most likely. createStore is probably most in line with the idea of the language here as it feels like this is what it is made for.

Comment: Thanks, both `Index` and `Key` will work in my case. Good to have an overview of the options.

Answer (score 0):

With `For`, whole element will be re-created when the item updates. You lose focus when you update the item because the element (input) with the focus gets destroyed, along with its parent (li), and a new element is created.

You have two options. You can either manually take focus when the new element is created or have a finer reactivity where element is kept while the property is updated. The `indexArray` provides the latter out of the box.

The `indexArray` keeps the element references while updating the item. The `Index` component uses `indexArray` under the hood.

```js
function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = createSignal([
    { id: 1, text: "cleanup" },
    { id: 2, text: "groceries" }
  ]);

  return (
    <ul>
      {indexArray(todos, (todo, index) => (
        <li>
          <input
            value={todo().text}
            onInput={(event) => {
              const text = event.target.value;
              setTodos(todos().map((v, i) => i === index ? { ...v, text } : v))
            }}
          />
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Note: `For` component caches the items internally to avoid unnecessary re-renders. Unchanged items will be re-used but updated ones will be re-created.

Comment: Thanks. Reading in the docs I see `indexArray` is used by `<Index>` under the hood, so I think this solution is effectively the same as using `<Index>`.

Comment: @JosdeJong Yes but Index wraps children in `createMemo` for extra layer of caching.